# Commenting out unwanted users in /etc/passwd file

Tags: bash

I need to compare all users in a .txt file to the /etc/passwd file and comment out all users who are not in the .txt file or at least tell me which users are not in the .txt file but are in the /etc/passwd file on the system.

Comment: Please be aware that all users with UID below 1000 are system users, and needed by the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by getting the essential information out of /etc/passwd, with the following command:

```
cut -d : -f 1 /etc/passwd > result.txt
```

This way you have a txt file only with the usernames. Then I suggest you use an easy **python or bash script** to compare those two files together and do what you want.

However I would not mess with the /etc/passwd file in a sense of editing it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I can take care of the commenting out in my script.

Answer (score 0):

Find all users from `/etc/passwd` that are not in your list:

```
awk -F':' 'NR==FNR{s[$1]++;next}!s[$1]{print $1}' users.list /etc/passwd
```

For commenting out, it can be easily done using `sed`.
But I leave that up to you to figure out as I very much agree with @andopr to not mess with `/etc/passwd` file.